# How to override views-view-row-rss.tpl.php in Views RSS page?

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I created custom template. It's located under templates dir of theme. Inside view settings, template is detected, however I am gettings always old RSS output (cache cleared). I want to add CDATA to description field.

It seems that my custom template is just omitted

Template file name: views-view-row-rss--feed.tpl.php

Comment: Put `<?php die(); ?>` in it. If Drupal will die, you will know it is used. If it will not die, you will know it is not executed.

Comment: @Mołot still works :(

Comment: When you say it is detected inside the view settings, make sure your presentation (front-end) theme is selected next to the "Change Theme" button.

Comment: @AdamBalsam thanks according to this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65101/rss-feed-page-customization it is impossible to do what I tried to accomplish